# Airflow installation problems

Tags: airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm trying to install Airflow on my laptop and I was able to do that using WSL but I can't seem to open it.

My webserver is running but  I cant open it on localhost:8080

[image]

The system is taking eons to run airflow scheduler

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend you use airflow with docker following the official guide https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: I would recommend running this on a Virtual Machine on your laptop rather than windows subsystem for linux.